# Route not defined laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to post a form in laravel an getting this error:

**Route [AdminController@postLogin] not defined**

```
// Controller


public function postLogin()
{
$rules = array(

'email' => 'required|email',
'password' => 'required'

);

$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

if($validation->fails())
{
return View::make('admin.login')->withErrors($validation);
}
else
{

}
}

// View
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="subwrapper">
@if($errors->has())
@foreach($errors as $error)
<p>{{ $error }}</p>
@endforeach
@endif
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@postLogin')) }}
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/><br />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
</div>
```

I have also tried adding seperate route and then routing the form to that using

```
Route::get('/adminshashishekhar', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index'));
Route::post('/postlogin', array('as' => 'postlogin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@postLogin'));
```

but then I get **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

Comment: Try using `{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'postlogin')) }}`?

Comment: @Sam No luck, still same issue.

Comment: Can you post the full error dump? It's hard to tell if the error is coming from the `routes.php` file (defining the route), the view (referring to the route), or the route dispatcher (trying to find the method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's something with the form.

```
Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@postLogin'))
```

I know Laravel allows the 'action', but I've never used it. I've only ever done:

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'postlogin'))
```

Now I have no idea if that will fix it, but could be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, second method worked like a  charm, but I don't understand first way is available in laravel's docs still does not work.

Comment: I know what you mean. It's possible `action => whatever` is a deprecated function in the latest version of Laravel, but who knows. 
Cheers!